# Problems with an OData filter and a Guid field

Tags: c#, odata

I’m trying to get some code working using OData. The following bit of code doesn’t seem to work.

**ds** is OpenDataServiceProxy.

**adapterTypeId** is the string representation of a Guid.

**adapterName** is a string name

```
ds.query('/DataAdapters?$filter=DataAdapterType.DataAdapterTypeId eq guid(\'' + adapterTypeId + '\') and Name eq \'' + adapterName + '\'', ifmgr_CreateAdapter_Step1, onGenericFailure, 'Error');
```

The above line give the following error:

Expression of type ‘System.Boolean’ expected at position 0.

If I remove the Guid section of the filter so that it’s just using the “Name” part it works fine.

The DataAdapters table field “DataAdapterTypeId” is foreign keyed to the “DataAdapterTypes” table DataAdapterTypeId field.

Can anyone spot what I’m doing wrong?

-------------------EDIT----------------------

OK, I've changed the filter as shown below. I no longer get an error but get lots of results back rather than one record that matches the filter. Can anyone say why it's not filtering?

```
ds.query('/DataAdapters?($filter=Name eq \'' + adapterName + '\' and $filter=DataAdapterTypeId eq guid\'' + adapterTypeId + '\')', ifmgr_CreateAdapter_Step1, onGenericFailure, '');
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The guid value needs to be formated like guid'' - see this for details: http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/overview#AbstractTypeSystem
Don't know what you wanted to achieve with the DataAdapterType.DataAdatperTypeId, but the dot character has no special meaning in the filter expression, so it probably doesn't do what you wanted. If your DataAdapters entity set has entities of type DataAdapterType, which then has a property DataAdapterTypeId which is of type GUID, then you can filter on it by simply

```
DataAdapterTypeId eq guid'<value>'
```

Comment: I made the changes you recommended but now I get all the records back, not just the one that matches the filter. I have added details to my original question.

Comment: Do not put parethesis around the $filters.

Comment: If yoy want two conditions use something like:
$filter=Name eq 'foo' and Description eq 'bar'

Comment: The syntax is fully described here: http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions

Comment: @VitekKarasMSFT None of the links seem to work anymore.

Comment: Notice there's no space between the 'guid' keyword and the value.

Answer (score 2):

With OData v4 what works for me on ASP.NET is

> 'DataAdapterTypeId eq ' + adapterTypeId

Observe no quotes or casts around the guid value. It will throw an error if `adapterTypeId` is not a GUID.

Comment: Removing the ' around my guid value worked for me. Thanks @m0s

Answer (score 0):

You can find the updated URL convention reference [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html).